# Can I render only Vray ExtraTex in 3ds Max

Tags: 3d, rendering, render, 3dsmax

I rendered a scene with some render elements : VrayExtraTex, VrayReflection, VraySpecular. 
The VrayExtraTex layer is not good, so i want to re-render but it tooks a lot of time. 
So i just want to re-render the VrayExtraTex layer but i don't know how.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

When I need to re-render a single element, I'll simplify the render settings:

Turn off:

- GI
- Lights
- Reflection/Refraction (maybe)

Now when your render will be much faster, but you may notice the quality is poor. Increase your AA settings, or turn on default lights. Play around with those things to get what you need.

What is your extraTex, dirt?

Also, save to .EXR format so you can access all your channels in one file.